# Doubts in Multiple inheritance in .net

Tags: .net, multiple-inheritance

We know that all the classes are inherited from the object class in .net. Say we create a class named ClassA. Then we create another class named ClassB that is inherited from ClassA. Isn't this multiple inheritance, because ClassB inherited from both Object class and ClassA? Doesn't this break the rule that C#.net doesn't support multiple inheritance?

Comment: And what is your question? Also, it's no counterexample, ClassB inherits from ClassA, which in it turn inherits from Object. ClassA does not inherit directly from Object..

Comment: Please ask a question if you have one.

Comment: Your example shows inheritance hierarchy, not multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is when ClassC inherit from ClassB and ClassA. You simply cant do this anyway in .NET because MI is not supported.

Comment: Hello guys... cool..
U jst take it in wrong way. My example is:
ClassB inherits from ClassA, ClassB is also inheting from Object class(as every class inherits from object class), isn't it a multiple inheritance?. My doubt arise here.

Comment: We understand what you are saying, Amit.

Comment: @Amit maybe real life example will help you understand where you are wrong. Suppose that every living being on the planet is called `LivingBeing`. You are of this type, your dog is of that type and even the germs living inside you. Now let's name something else: `Human`. This class describe something that is both living being *and* human. You inherit from it, but your dog or germs are not. Now for example let's add one last class: `WalkingOnFour` - whoever inherit from it (like your dog) is also living being but you can't be both `Human` and `WalkingOnFour` as those are separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not break the rule.  Since ClassA is an object, it does not mean that you're inheriting from 2 different classes.  You're inheriting from ClassA, and thereby taking all the characteristics from the 'inheritance chain' with it.
You're not inheriting from 2 different types, since ClassA is an object.

Answer (score 2):

You do not understand what multiple inheritance is.  From wikipedia:

> Multiple inheritance refers to a feature of some object-oriented programming languages in which a class can inherit behaviors and features from more than one superclass.

From wikipedia's entry on superclass:

> A superclass, base class, or parent class is a class from which other classes are derived. The classes that are derived from a superclass are known as child classes, derived classes, or subclasses.

In your example, ClassA inherits from object.  ClassB inherits from ClassA.  ClassA is the superclass of ClassB.  Object is not a superclass of ClassB.  Your example is not multiple inheritance.  There is one parent, one child.